# How can I pass unique id fields from a Model to a Django form when looping through model in a template?

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-2.0

I need to create unique id for each form that is generated from a loop in Django templates. I use `{% for product in products %}` to loop through some data. In my `forms.py` I edit the form.widget.Select attributes to add/change the `onchange` and `id` fields. I render it through `views.py` and my templates as `{{form}}`, Here is the line in `forms.py`:

```
condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=condition_choices, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange' : "showChange(this)", "id":"{{product.id}}"}))
```

I expected the id to render as a unique id associated with each product, and I expected the onchange to call a `js` function. When I print the form to the console, it looks like this:

```
<select name="condition" onchange="showChange(this)" id="{{product.id}}">
  <option value="NM / LP">Near Mint / Lightly Played</option>

  <option value="MP">Moderately Played</option>

  <option value="HP">Heavily Played</option>

  <option value="Damaged">Damaged</option>

  <option value="Unopened">Unopened</option>

</select>
```

I would expect the id field to be the actual id and not `{{product.id}}`
If this form is pasted exactly into html without rendering it as a Django form, it works as expected. How can I pass my product's unique id to Django forms without importing the Database into `forms.py`/extra Database calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `{{product.id}}` in .py files. It's a Django template engine tag.

In your **views.py** you should create your form like this:

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=1)

form = ProductForm(instance=product)

context = {
    'form': form
}
```

when you pass the form then you can use it's data in the `__init__` method.

and your form will look like this

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Product
    exclude = ()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    self.fields['condition'].widget.attrs['id'] = instance.id
```